# How to suppress stderr while using 'ls' command along with assigning the output to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh

I am trying to create a script that would search for files on the server as per their name and time stamp and take count of those files into a variable. It works fine when the file is available, but throws an stderr when the file is not available.

In order to suppress the stderr I am trying to redirect it to /dev/null but even that is not helping and the error still shows on the screen. I know I can first check whether the file is available or not using the 'if' statement and then take the count but that would unnecessarily make the script lengthy.

So is there a way I can take the file count and suppress the stderr (if any) along with assigning the output to a variable in just one line of code?

This command runs successfully when a file with name 'example' is present on the server:

```
file_name=example
file_date=20190901

file_count=`ls -lrt "$PWD"/"$file_name"*"$file_date"* | wc -l`
```

But when the file is not present, it throws a stderr on the screen like below:

```
ls: cannot access /home/saurap01/example*20190901*: No such file or directory
```

In order to suppress this error, I tried redirecting it to /dev/null as below:

```
file_count=`ls -lrt "$PWD"/"$file_name"*"$file_date"* | wc -l` > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But even this is not helping in suppressing the error.

Can I just try to hide the stderr by using below:

```
file_count=`ls -lrt "$PWD"/"$file_name"*"$file_date"* | wc -l` 2>&-
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Why do use `-r` and `-t`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not redirecting stderr correctly, `2>/dev/null` should come right after the command whose stderr you want to supress, like:

```
file_count=`ls -lrt "$PWD"/"$file_name"*"$file_date"* 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
```

**But,** [parsing the output of `ls` is not a good idea at all](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you should use `find` for tasks like this. For example, using GNU find:

```
find -maxdepth 1 \
     -type f \
     -name "$file_name*$file_date*" \
     -printf '.' | wc -c
```

or using any POSIX-compliant find:

```
find . \
! \( -type d -path '*/*' -prune \) \
     -type f \
     -name "$file_name*$file_date*" \
     -exec printf '.%.s' {} + | wc -c
```

Comment: Thank you!
Using the redirecting the stderr worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate solution is to add

```
2>/dev/null
```

*inside* the command substitution.

Your code exhibits a number of antipatterns, so let's also discuss those.

As explained in [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls), the shell already performs wildcard expansions before passing the arguments to `ls`. Moreover, the options you pass to `ls` perform a nontrivial amount of additional work; you ignore the size, owner etc yet you cause these to be looked up with the `-l` option; and you don't care about the sort order, yet you force sorting by timestamp with `-rt`.

Additionally, as explained in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, the command `ls` has a number of features for human-readable output which make it unsuitable for use in scripts.

The shell, out of the box, is usually configured with globbing set up to return the glob pattern itself if it doesn't match any files. In Bash (but not `ksh`) you can avoid this with

```
setopt -s nullglob
```

and then simply print the files;

```
### BUG; see below
printf '%s\n' ./"$file_name"*"$file_date"* |
wc -l
```

However, this will produce the wrong result if one of the file names contains a newline - then, the number of lines of output will be different than the number of files. An easy workaround is to avoid the `printf` and use the shell's features entirely.

```
set -- ./"$file_name"*"$file_date"*
```

Thrs will simply assign the wildcard matches to the list of arguments `$1`, `$2` etc, and hence

```
echo $#
```

will print the number of files.

If you don't have Bash (and thus not `shopt`) you can look for whether the glob expands to itself by checking whether the first file exists.

```
set -- ./"$file_name"*"$file_date"*
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "$#"
else
    echo 0
fi
```

As a minor aside, notice also that `"$PWD"` is rarely useful to spell out. If you need to convert a relative file name to absolute, or need to know the full path of the current directory for other reasons, it's occasionally useful; but outside of these scenarios, just use the relative path to refer to things in the current directory.

Comment: Please do not use `shopt` (GNU bash only) in a question (additionally) tagged [tag:ksh], thanks!

Comment: @mirabilos It's really not clear which shell the OP is targeting here, due to the conflicting or at least confusing tags; but thanks for the remark; I'll mark this specifically as Bash-only.

Comment: Indeed, many shell questions are tagged both. I usually go with the subset in this case or just POSIX sh, then (__if necessary__) point the shell-specific ones out as add-on _afterwards_. Thanks for considering!

Comment: The usual way to avoid the nullglob is to test the first argument for existence. I commonly write things like `for x in *; do [[ -e $x ]] || break; dosomethingwith *; break; done` (a loop run only once, ofc could also use `&&`). Here, you could just `test -e "$1"` to catch it.

Comment: @mirabilos Good point; I have included a short passage about this.